# cant fetch data thru drop down value

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

i have a SELECT box in which value was populated from database, below is the code

```
<select name="ea_name" id="ea_name">
<option value="" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
<?php 
require 'include/DB_Open.php';
$sql = "SELECT ea_name FROM ea_error ORDER BY ea_name";
$myData = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<option value=\"$ea_name\">" . $row['ea_name'] . "</option>";
}
include 'include/DB_Close.php';
?>
</select>
```

now i have a jquery so that when SELECT value changes it would pull up the data from db and populate it to a textarea

```
$("#ea_name").on("change", function() {
$.ajax({
url: "retrieve.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
ea_name: $(this).val()
},
success: function(data) {
$("#results").html(data);
}
});
});
});
});
```

here is my query now,

```
<?php
require 'include/DB_Open.php';

$ea_name = $_POST['ea_name'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM ea_error WHERE ea_name = '" . $ea_name . "'";
echo $sql;

$myData = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

//to count if there are any results
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($myData) ;

if($numrow == 0)
{
    echo "No results found.";
}
else
{
echo '<fieldset><legend><strong>Information</strong></legend>
<table width="619" border="0" align="center">
<tr><th scope="row">Error</th></tr>
<tr><th scope="row">Resolution</th></tr>
<tr><th scope="row">Contact/s</th></tr>';

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
{
echo "<form action='retrieve.php' method='post'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . "<textarea readonly=readonly name=error cols=75 rows=10> " . $info['error'] . "</textarea></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . "<textarea readonly=readonly name=resolution cols=75 rows=10> " . $info['resolution'] . "</textarea></td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . "<textarea readonly=readonly name=contacts cols=75 rows=10> " . $info['contacts'] . "</textarea></td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "</form>";
}
}
echo "</fieldset>"; 

include 'include/DB_Close.php';
?>
```

i've added `echo $sql;` so i can see the output and here is what im getting: **SELECT * FROM ea_error WHERE ea_name = ''No results found.**

i tried to view the source and im seeing this:

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: ea_name in **C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\view_transactions.php** on line **75**
Switches

line 75 refers to this `echo "<option value=\"$ea_name\">" . $row['ea_name'] . "</option>";`

i need help in understanding and fixing this error...im new to php coding...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ea_name` is not defined anywhere that dont have any value I think your looking for this one

```
echo "<option value=\"$row['ea_name']\">" . $row['ea_name'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: thanks for shedding some light here, i just modified your code though to this: `echo "<option value= '" . $row['ea_name'] . "'>" . $row['ea_name'] . "</option>";`